# Boost::binary<>

Tags: c++, boost

Is there anything in boost libraries like binary? For example I would like to write:

```
binary<10101> a;
```

I'm ashamed to admit that I've tried to find it (Google, Boost) but no results. They're mention something about binary_int<> but I couldn't find neither if it is available nor what header file shall I include;

Thanks for help.

Comment: On gcc you can use `0b10101`.

Comment: Such a template would be the kind of thing that would cause some massive code bloat. Same thing happens with the boost::assign:: templates.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is the [`BOOST_BINARY`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#BOOST_BINARY) macro. used like this

```
int array[BOOST_BINARY(1010)];
  // equivalent to int array[012]; (decimal 10)
```

To go with your example:

```
template<int N> struct binary { static int const value = N; };
binary<BOOST_BINARY(10101)> a;
```

Once some compiler supports C++0x's user defined literals, you could write

```
template<char... digits>
struct conv2bin;

template<char high, char... digits>
struct conv2bin<high, digits...> {
    static_assert(high == '0' || high == '1', "no bin num!");
    static int const value = (high - '0') * (1 << sizeof...(digits)) + 
                             conv2bin<digits...>::value;
};

template<char high>
struct conv2bin<high> {
    static_assert(high == '0' || high == '1', "no bin num!");
    static int const value = (high - '0');
};

template<char... digits>
constexpr int operator "" _b() {
    return conv2bin<digits...>::value;
}

int array[1010_b];
```

Comment: I just looked at the source - I think I'll stick with hex :-)

Comment: @Neil so how long did it take to get the "legendary" badge? I'm trying hard, but it seems difficult to get it :)

Comment: Oh, it's easy - you simply need to have nothing better to do with your time. It's silly to be proud of any badge of course, but I am kind of proud of the the silver "stl" badge, because of the select bunch of people it has been awarded to :-)

Comment: @Neil, ah i see. I'm really glad tho that herb sutter joined stackoverflow today: http://stackoverflow.com/users/297582/herb-sutter . Now C++ has a real-world expert and committee member on SO too.

Comment: That is good news, but I wonder how long he'll last? Other well known figures such as the ghastly "Uncle Bob" Martin have shown up here and then vanished again. I wonder how long Herb can put up with being repeatedly asked what the meaning of ++++x is.